# Use Gtk.ComboBox with a Gtk.TreeStore in PyGObject

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I would like to have a `Gtk.ComboBox` with elements displayed like a tree. It means some of the rows should have indention depending on there level in the tree.

When I interprete the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/ComboBox.html#Gtk.ComboBox) correct it should be possible with using a `Gtk.TreeStore` as data structure (model) behinde the control.

Maybe I am missinterpreting the docu and it is not possible to use `Gtk.TreeStore` with it?

But it doesn't work in my example. I have experience with `Gtk.TreeStore` and `Gtk.TreeView`.

The example code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        # The Model
        store = Gtk.TreeStore(int, str)
        # first item in the row is an internal ID that should not
        # be displayed in the combo box
        it = store.append(parent=None, row=[1, "Eins"])
        it = store.append(parent=it, row=[2, "Zwei"])
        it = store.append(parent=it, row=[3, "Drei"])

        # expected result
        # Eins
        # |- Zwei
        #  |- Drei

        # The View
        combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(store)
        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        combo.pack_start(renderer, False)
        combo.add_attribute(renderer, "text", 1)

        box = Gtk.VBox()
        box.add(combo)
        self.add(box)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

A visual example
[image]

Comment: And how do you propose to render a combobox this way? The subentries will hide the top level entries, resulting in an unusable combobox.

Comment: I added a visual example and improved the title to make clear that I need a ComboBox and nothing else.

Comment: Why not use a Gtk.ListStore and add extra spaces for indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it that it is not possible to use a `Gtk.ComboBox` with a `Gtk.TreeStore` like data structure inside.

There is only the workaround with indentions.